# select records with condition on other field?

Tags: mysql, select

Maybe someone can help.

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

I try to select all ids, with ALL status equal to 2 or 4.
So it should result id = 1, because all status with id=1 are 2 or 4.

How can I do that?

Thanks!
Leo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "with ALL status equal to 2 or 4" means "both 2 and 4 are present" then

```sql
SELECT id
FROM test
GROUP BY id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT status ORDER BY status) = '2,4';
```

---

If "with ALL status equal to 2 or 4" means "either only 2 or only 4 or both" then

```sql
SELECT id
FROM test
GROUP BY id
HAVING NOT SUM(status NOT IN (2,4));
```

Comment: The second solution is what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT EXISTS to check if there are others than 2 or 4. See example below.

```
select distinct np.id
from NotProvidedName as np
where not exists (select * from NotProvidedName npn WHERE npn.id = np.id and npn.status not in (2,4))
```

Next time, please provide the scripts to create objects and the data to play with.

Example in fiddlr:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aed22f/6

Answer (score 0):

Would this also be a good solution?

```
SELECT id 
FROM test 
WHERE id not in (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM test WHERE status not IN (2,4));
```

Comment: This is a solution, but in most cases it is slower than the same solution with NOT EXISTS or LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL. You may improve it slightly by removing DISTINCT which causes excess and unnesessary sorting.